# django get distinct foreignkeys from queryset

Tags: mysql, django, performance, django-queryset

I have a big django MySQL database and im struggling to get this to work efficiently :

models.py :

```
class Category(models.Model)
    name = models.CharField()

class Article(models.Model)
    start_date = models.DateTimeField(...)
    end_date = models.DateTimeField(...)
    active = models.BooleanField(...)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField( Category )
```

I'd like to get all the **active** categories based on Article queryset. I actually do it this way :

```
actives_articles = Articles.objects.filter(start_date__gt = datetime.datetime.today(), end_date__lt = another_date, active = True)
actives_categories = Category.objects.filter(article__in = actives_articles).distinct().order_by('name')
```

`actives_articles` return about 50k results so this is not efficient at all.

Any idea or pointers ?

Thanks !

Comment: what do __gt, __in mean?
havent seen them before!

Answer (score 0):

I finally got something working with this :

```
now = datetime.datetime.now()
filters  = {
    'article__active': True,
    'article__start_date__lte':now,
    'article__end_date__gte':now,
}
categs = Category.objects.filter(**filters).distinct()
```

silly me and thanks Django !